# Aligning two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have two images of the same shoe sole, one taken with a scanning machine and another with a digital camera. I want to scale one of the images so that it can be easily aligned with the other without having to do it all by hand.

My thought was to use edge detection, connect all the points on the outside of the shoe, scale one image to fit right inside the other, and then scale the original image at the same rate.

I've messed around using different tools in the Image Processing toolbox in MatLab, but am making no progress.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Try to find the center of mass of the set of points and the main axes of inertia.

Comment: Need to see your images.

Answer (score -1):

My advise would be to firstly use the function `activecontour` to obtain the outer contour of the shoe on both images. Then use the function `procrustes` with the binary images as input.

```
[~, CameraFittedToScan] = procrustes(Scan,Camera);
```

This transforms the camera image to best fit with the scanned image. If the scan and camera are not the same size then this needs to be adjusted first using the function `imresize`.